# merge and sort two sorted text file

Tags: python, sorting, text, merge, mergesort

I have two text files:

#### sample-r1.txt

```
Bud Abbott 51 92.3
Mary Boyd 52 91.4
Hillary Clinton 50 82.1
```

#### sample-r2.txt

```
Don Adams 51 90.4
Jill Carney 53 76.3
Randy Newman 50 41.2
```

I want to merge and order them with last name which is second index of each line (program may NOT use any pre-existing merging or sorting software)

these is my code

```
one = open("sample-r1.txt",'r')
two = open("sample-r2.txt",'r')

for line in one:
    k = line.rstrip().split('\t')

for record in two:
    h= record.rstrip().split('\t')

i=0
j=0
newList=[]

while i < len(k) and j<len(h) :
    if k[i][1] <= h[j][1]:
        newList.append(k[i])
        i+=1            
    else:
        newList.append(h[j])
        j+=1

print(newList)
```

Comment: fix your indentation please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: few fixes: k,h.append instead of k,h= otherwise k and h are list and k[][] is a char instead of a string

```
one = open("sample-r1.txt",'r')
two = open("sample-r2.txt",'r')
k=[]
h=[]
for line in one:
    tmp=line.rstrip().split('\t')
    if len(tmp)>1:
        k.append ( tmp )
for record in two:
    tmp=record.rstrip().split('\t')
    if len(tmp)>1:
        h.append ( tmp )
i=0
j=0
newList=[]
while i < len(k) and j < len(h):
    if k[i][1] <= h[j][1]:
        newList.append(k[i])
        i+=1
    else:
        newList.append(h[j])
        j+=1
while i < len(k):
    newList.append(k[i])
    i+=1
while j < len(h):
    newList.append(h[j])
    j+=1
for row in newList:
    print("\t".join(row))
```

Comment: thx it's better but there is a error shows in if k[i][1] <= h[j][1]:
IndexError: list index out of range.thx for help.

Comment: what is the condition you are using in while? maybe len(k[i]) or len(h[j]) are <1, these lines can be filter in for loops

Comment: it print empty [] out after doing your code, dont know why. and confused at len(k)or len(h)<1? since the text file is not empty. thx

Comment: maybe the condition len(tmp)==4 is too restrictive, len(tmp)>1 would suffice to avoid the IndexError, adapt to your situation

Comment: sorry to say that it print out same thing, only a [].

Answer (score 0):

First it's not clear that your input is tab delimited. Use `split()` instead of `split('\t')` to make sure you get all the columns.

Second your `while` loop terminates when either input is exhausted, but the other input will still have some data remaining. That should have been obvious by the output being too short.